# Find the column that has a certain total number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If:

```
sum(list(map(lambda x : sum(len(y) for y in x.split()), df['column2'].iloc[3])))
```

gets the total character in row number 3 of column number 2 in pandas dataframe **df**, then **how to find the column that has a certain total number** (for example: which index column has the total number of character of 43,382) ?

**EDITED**:
I tried this rather long code:

```
df.loc[df['column2'] == (sum(list(map(lambda x : sum(len(y) for y in x.split()), df['column2'])))).isin('43382')]
```

but I got error message:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

This is how my dataframe **df** looks like"

```
column1      column2                                            column3
amsterdam    school yeah right backtic escapes sport swimming   2016
rotterdam    nope yeah                                          2012
thehague     i now i can fly no you cannot swimming rope        2010
amsterdam    sport cycling in the winter makes me               2019
```

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Get the number of characters for each element, then find the max? What is the issue, exactly? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: it's simple actually @AMC: get the column index of a certain total character in a row

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani Alright, so what’s the issue?

Comment: apparently using `.isin` or `.eq` to state certain value of the total character in a row doesn't work. it says `'int' object has no attribute 'isin'` and `'int' object has no attribute 'eq'`

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani Again, what is the issue here?

Comment: What are the contents of your DataFrame, by the way? Where is the [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by summing all the characters for each rows and return it to a new column = **column4**:

```
df['column4'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: sum(len(y) for y in x.split()))
```

and then simply just look at the desire character's total count with this code:

```
df[df['column4']== 43382]
```

Comment: Your post mentions _for example: which index column has the total number of character of 43,382_, but you're not counting characters, you're counting words, right?

Comment: No @AMC . I'm counting the character's not words

Comment: I reread the code, and it seems you're indeed counting characters, minus whitespace, although I'm not sure how effective the whitespace deletion is. It's probably clearer and more reliable to use `df['column2'].map(lambda curr_str: sum(char != ' ' for char in curr_str))`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `.isin(['43382'])`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: still doesn't work. it says:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isin'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eq` instead:

```
print(df[(sum(list(map(lambda x : sum(len(y) for y in x.split()), df['column2'])))) == ('43382')].dropna())
```

Comment: still doesn't work. it says:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'eq'`